# Laravel Sail & Docker Adding Additional Sites (Multi Project)

Tags: macos, docker, homestead, laravel-8, laravel-sail

It is now recommended to use Sail & Docker with Laravel 8

Now I use homestead, but I wanted to upgrade my system to the latest version 8 and I did the setup before I installed the Docker Desktop and Sail http: // localhost everything works, however nodejs npm and mysql redis are ready for everything

The topic I want to learn is sail & docker, how does multiple projects work in this structure?
For example Homestead before working on this config

```
- map: homestead.test
to: /home/vagrant/project1/public

- map: another.test
to: /home/vagrant/project2/public
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the ports (MySQL, Redis, MailHog etc.) if you want to run multiple projects at the same time.

### Application, MySQL, and Redis Ports

Add the desired ports to the `.env` file:

```
APP_PORT=81
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
FORWARD_REDIS_PORT=6380
```

### MailHog Ports

Update MailHog ports in the `docker-compose.yml` file. Change these lines:

```yaml
ports:
    - 1025:1025
    - 8025:8025
```

to this:

```yaml
ports:
    - 1026:1025
    - 8026:8025
```

Once the containers have been started, you can access your application at `http://localhost:81` and the MailHog web interface at `http://localhost:8026`.

Comment: Currently every service support ENV variables, so even mailhog ports can be set via .env file. Check `docker-compose.yml` to see the right variable name for every service.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You have to change to all non-conflict ports for all Laravel Sail project.

If you want to use custom domain like what you did in Homestead,

you can use the [Nginx Proxy](https://github.com/jc21/nginx-proxy-manager) to achieve Multiple Project just like Homestead

Here is my article: [step-by-step tutorial](https://medium.com/p/e13c07d9dd0c) you can follow with....

Comment: FYI, you need to clearly disclose that you're the author the the linked post as per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). I also noticed a few of your other answers link back to your blog (with disclosing it's your blog) which might be marked as spam. That said, your article on Medium was helpful though, so thank you.